# ag-grid in vue display custom component when loading the rows

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

Am trying to display the v-progress-circular vuetify component when ag-grid is loading the rows, i have been following the ag-grid documentation but that doesn't seems to work. the ag-grid documentation for vue seems to be outdated so i don't know what to do. What i have done so far is the following:

TableProgress.vue

```
<template>
  <v-progress-circular :value="20" color="primary" indeterminate>
  </v-progress-circular>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'TableProgress'
}
</script>
```

MyTable.vue (Relevant parts)

```
<template>
  <ag-grid-vue
      :grid-options="gridOptions"
      class="ag-theme-material"
      :frameworkComponents="frameworkComponents"
      :loadingOverlayComponent="loadingOverlayComponent"
  />
</template>
<script>
  import TableProgress from "./TableProgress";

  export default{
    data(){
      return{
        gridOptions: null,
        frameworkComponents: null,
        loadingOverlayComponent: null
      }
    },
    beforeMount () {
      this.frameworkComponents = {
        tableProgress: TableProgress
      }
      this.gridOptions.loadingOverlayComponent = 'tableProgress'
      this.loadingOverlayComponent = 'tableProgress'
    },
  }
</script>
```

What am i doing wrong here? Or is it that this simply doesn't work on vue?

Comment: You must add export default after the import

Comment: @Ady642 Am sorry, i fixed my post that's not the problem

Comment: You must add the component. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the attribute is `overlayLoadingTemplate` in ag-grid instead of `loadingOverlayComponent`. Kindly visit [ag-grid overlays](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlays/) to see how you can add loader to your ag-grid table

Comment: I was reading this: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlay-component/

Answer (score 0):

You import the TableProgress but you don't use it. You must add it in components.

```
<script> 
import TableProgress from "./TableProgress"; 
export default {
    components: { 
        TableProgress
    },
    //... 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered "low-effort" answers and are generally not very good, because they provide very little insight for the community. Please improve your answer by explaining the solution you are suggesting as an answer. You can read how to write a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Can you expand on how to use the TableProgress when declared as components?

Doing `:loadingOverlayComponent="TableProgress"`

would currently result in an error `component has been registered but not used`